# How can I test my server with an Australian web client?

Tags: testing, networking, cloud, delay

I have an app running on a web server in the Heroku cloud. The server is in Ireland. The client is written using React.

Users from Australia (working with Windows/Firefox) report bugs that are seemingly caused by the long network delays (more than 500 milliseconds from Australia to Ireland!).

How can I rent a client computer in Australia so that I can connect to it via screen sharing, run a browser there and see for myself what happens when I use the app in Ireland?

Is there a cloud service in Australia that offers simple Windows boxes with remote desktop access?

Answer (score 1):

There are several option to test slow connections:

- On Windows, use Clumsy to simulate long ping times. You can also throttle, and simulate packet loss. On Linux there's a lot of options, although Netem is probably the most popular.
- Use some kind of proxy that provides this functionality, like Charles.
- Use your browser dev tools, both Chrome and Firefox have options to throttle to different bandwidths
- Pick a VPN in Australia.
- Finally, you can get a box in Australia using AWS (Sydney Region), or Vultr.

Comment: Thanks, Reinhold for the hints! I subscribed to Vultr and to AWS, each with one server in Sydney. Works. Vultr continues to charge me even if my server is shut down. AWS charges by the hour. Good enough for me.